# Позиция возвратного местоимения "себя"

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, интонация

*Эксплуатировать **себя** за копЕйки // они не позволят.*

*Эксплуатировать за копЕйки // они **себя** не позволят.*

При помощи инверсии хочу логически выделить сочетание "эксплуатировать за копейки". Местоимение "себя" намерен перенести во вторую фразу: 1) объект эксплуатации не подчёркивается, 2) местоимение помешает выделению — удлинит фразу и без надобности перетянет на себя часть внимания. Кстати, в случае переноса в качестве бонуса мы получим равновесие двух фраз.

Является ли грамматически корректным отрыв возвратного местоимения "себя" от глагола, к которому он относится, — как в моём предложении, так и в русском языке в целом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***(1) Эксплуатировать себя за копЕйки // они не позвОлят.***

***(2) Эксплуатировать за копЕйки // они себя не позвОлят.***

Чем неудачно предложение (2)?

1) **Нужной инверсии там нет**, то есть перестановка местоимения ***себя*** ничего не дает.  Расстановка ударений не изменилась (в обоих случаях оно приходится на конец первой фразы), поэтому и нет логического выделения нужного слова.

Сравнить: ***Работать задАром//они не будут. ― ЗадАром работать// они не будут.*** В этом предложении инверсия позволяет  выделить логическим ударением наречие. Так работает инверсия.

2) Попробуем перестроить предложение по этому же образцу.

***За копЕйки эксплуатировать // они себя не позволят.***

Теперь нужное слово выделено логическим ударением, но перенос местоимения из одной части предложения (темы)  в другую (в рему) не кажется стилистически корректным, хотя оно, вероятно, и допустимо.

Положение местоимения ***себя*** достаточно свободно, но обычно перемещение осуществляется **в пределах одной фонетической фразы**, например:

В университете себя человЕком чувствуешь,// свободным и гОрдым!

Answer (score 2):

> Является ли грамматически корректным отрыв возвратного местоимения
>   "себя" от глагола, к которому он относится, — как в моём предложении,
>   так и в русском языке в целом?

Без проблем. Можете переносить в любую часть, если считаете нужным. 
Вообще непонятно, откуда такая идея могла возникнуть, что нельзя. "Себя" в принципе не очень привязано к глаголу, важно чтобы он был или хотя бы подразумевался.

А вот что касается вашей развернутой "прелюдии" к вопросу, то тут просто наверчено бог знает что. Какие там "бонус", "инверсия", какое "равновесие"...
Какие-то вообще странные представления о стилистике, если не о грамматике.
В двух ваших примерах никакого интонационного ударения на конкретном слове я не просматриваю. Но, конечно же, согласиться с тем, что фраза стала более корявой я не могу. Если такой подход кажется автору более выразительным - то флаг в руки.

Ну а если вам надо сделать акцент на себя, то вынесете его вперед. 
***Себя эксплуатировать за копейки они не позволят.***

Да, это субъективное восприятие, но в таких вопросах объективного вообще не так много.

Comment: Наоборот, акцента на "себя" нет, поэтому и хочется его убрать во вторую фразу. Про "равновесие": предложение состоит из двух фраз — с восходящей и с нисходящей тональностью. Во втором предложении эти фразы становятся равными по длине.

Comment: *Наоборот, акцента на "себя" нет, поэтому и хочется его убрать во вторую фразу.* - что "наоборот"?" Не наоборот, а именно так. Акцента на "себя" нету, куда не переставляй. Ну разве что в начало.

Answer (score 1):

Это ещё один пример, подчеркивающий, что надо быть проще и выбирать наиболее естественный порядок слов. Ибо при инверсии вы ничего логически не выделяете, а вот фраза становится более корявой. Хотя и остаётся грамматически корректной.